# AWS: What is the difference between Augmented Manifest File and Manifest File?

Tags: amazon-web-services, manifest, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to learn how to use AWS Sagemaker, and I've stumbled upon a setting for input data to either be a Manifest File or and Augmented Manifest File. When creating a training job through the Sagemaker console, I have seen in the **Input data configuration** section that it is not possible to use this combination of settings:

```
Input mode = File
S3 data type = AugmentedManifestFile
```

as this results in the error `Pipe mode is required for AugmentedManifestFile S3 data type.`.

In the **Input data configuration** section, I can also choose the attribute names for the AgumentedManifestFile, which I cannot for the ManifestFile option. Is this because all Manifest Files must follow the same template, whereas Augmented Manifest Files lets you decide the template?

Furthermore, I have also seen in [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/incremental-training.html) that the Manifest File can be used for incremental training, but not the Augmented Manifest File. I am trying to puzzle together the pieces, but I don't seem to get the whole picture of their difference.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `ManifestFile` and `AugmentedManifestFile` is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_S3DataSource.html#SageMaker-Type-S3DataSource-S3DataType

There is also more detailed information about `AugmentedManifestFiles` here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/augmented-manifest.html

To be able to use `AugmentedManifestFiles` you have to use an algorithm that is able to read the data format and so, yes, the examples in the incremental training tutorial you mention cannot use this form.